# If the module of Kahler differentials $\Omega_R$ is free than $\operatorname{rk} \Omega_R = \operatorname{dim} R$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, and $R$ is a (local as ring with maximal ideal $m$) algebra over $k$ of essentially finite type, such that 
$$
k \cong R/m.
$$
It is easy to show that if the module of Kahler differentials  $\Omega_R$ is free of rank $d=\operatorname{dim} R$ than $R$ is a regular ring. This follows from conormal sequence for the maximal ideal of $R$. But, in fact, it is enough to assume that  $\Omega_R$ is free (without any assumption on rank of $\Omega_R$) to conclude that $R$ is regular and thus $\operatorname{rk} \Omega_R = \operatorname{dim} R$. Where can I find a proof of this stronger statement?

Comment: When you write $\Omega_R$, do you mean $\Omega_{R/k}$? If so, take $R=k(t)$, then $\Omega_R$ is free of rank one, but dimension of $k(t)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I added additional assumption that I forgot.

Comment: I still think you need to assume that $R$ is essentially finite type or something. If $R=k[[x]]$, I think $\Omega_{R/k}$ is still too big.

Comment: Again you are absolutely right: I'm only interested in e.f.t., I added this to the question.